How to use a router as an extender when it works from channels 1 to 11 when the main router only switches between channels 6 and 13?
I was using an old router (TP-Link) to use it as an wireless extender to my main router.
The problem is that the main router channel is in auto, so that it provides the best signal and it mostly switches between channels 6 and 13.
Now, my TP-Link router has only option of channel selection from 1 to 11. So whenever the main router goes to 13, the TP-Link no longer can scan that WiFi for extending its signal and will be without WiFi.
I have downloaded the latest firmware and still I couldn't find a solution.
Some suggest change region of router, but I don't find that option anymore.

Take it off auto

Routers are region locked from a radio perspective where they are sold in the world. That’s been the case for nearly a decade. Governments really came down on the market about a decade ago.

@Ramhound: Seems like it's the USA with FCC, mostly. Over here I've never had a region-locked wireless router, but I've seen some manufacturers' product pages say "This device is sold in two versions: US (locked to channels 1-11) and international (unlocked)". I did have some routers that would only let you select the country once though, and then you had to factory-reset it to change it again, so I'm guessing OP's might be similar – either that or it's an ISP-issued one with half the settings hidden...

@grawity_u1686 - EU came down hard on the radio configurations also around the same time. US and EU forced the radio manufacturers to lockdown the channels through channels.

Normally, auto results in poor performance compared to setting an actual channel. Generally, channels 1,6, or 11 is recommended, with 6 usually being preferred (to understand why, search for what channels are covered by each of those - 6 covers channels below and above it)
